# dropzone - one picture in another dimension

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js, dimension

Is possible generate one photo in another dimension than rest thumbnails?
So example: first photo should have 200px width and 400px height and next photos should have only 100px width and 200px height.

I have searched only those options for all images:

```
thumbnailWidth: 100,
thumbnailHeight: 100,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the [resize function](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-resize) with your own logic and for your first image apply different size

```
var dropzoneSettings = {
    resize: function(file) {
            var info, srcRatio, trgRatio;
            info = {
              srcX: 0,
              srcY: 0,
              srcWidth: file.width,
              srcHeight: file.height
            };
            srcRatio = file.width / file.height;
            info.optWidth = this.options.thumbnailWidth;
            info.optHeight = this.options.thumbnailHeight;
            if ((info.optWidth == null) && (info.optHeight == null)) {
              info.optWidth = info.srcWidth;
              info.optHeight = info.srcHeight;
            } else if (info.optWidth == null) {
              info.optWidth = srcRatio * info.optHeight;
            } else if (info.optHeight == null) {
              info.optHeight = (1 / srcRatio) * info.optWidth;
            }
            trgRatio = info.optWidth / info.optHeight;
            if (file.height < info.optHeight || file.width < info.optWidth) {
              info.trgHeight = info.srcHeight;
              info.trgWidth = info.srcWidth;
            } else {
              if (srcRatio > trgRatio) {
                info.srcHeight = file.height;
                info.srcWidth = info.srcHeight * trgRatio;
              } else {
                info.srcWidth = file.width;
                info.srcHeight = info.srcWidth / trgRatio;
              }
            }
            info.srcX = (file.width - info.srcWidth) / 2;
            info.srcY = (file.height - info.srcHeight) / 2;
            return info;
          }
}
$("#my-dropzone").dropzone(dropzoneSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to determine first image, so what should I check in "file" parameter to check that this is first image?

Comment: you can get the index of the file with this.files.indexOf(file)  or you can use the file name (file.name)